# can't locate element in iframe selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm Trying to switch to frame on a web page to access a video in that frame but error always occur that element is not find i've tried many elements all the same error

this is the code i used to switch to the frame and get the video url

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@id = 'innerframe']/iframe")))

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//video[@id='mediaplayer']/soucre").text
```

here is the html of the page [HTML PAGE](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak2B5zunl0Z9akIkEc4VZmNTtKU)

```
        <div id="innerframe"><iframe src="https://ops.cielo24.com/hitman/work/load_task/554097cdbe314edb9ad5d62edf5396ed/tasks/2547efb19fc5430c9f335fe165a46df3?active_task_uuid=44686eab1ad8448d97e5e74e484575ab" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

video html:

```
<div id="mediacontent">
    <video height="305" width="480" id="mediaplayer"><source src="https://c24cdn.co/restricted/sliced-media/790f319ee29c46e585c5ee585ed31580.mp4?Expires=1584401901&amp;GoogleAccessId=microservice-writer%40coresystem-171219.iam.gserviceaccount.com&amp;Signature=QtSAPQc5GMxPx9qAI8WnCurouFagNgRE2rto1B3af%2BrUhemeqoFnJZWmfQfQ2SGXKAhc5pXL68GhLINlshZ4yGEvy7SDMEr1l44Z%2FA9bFL3Xvlsii9MfZpkXaCeXT%2FKrMZZvH%2BpbiR%2BpgQjgqLysP68fODMsQ3zub9FCx8zD2Yw5bQZg12rzQWdlEcU5VHGktTSDAjpReWHIrmca63X6jQAYru5TQi12sy18UwSlpdrF1qFgXlTOEMKwB2iPHbLRPxxpFF%2FhOkYVrCcIi6OmJOXvy6arBZY9%2FYBP2vjIpDQ3UODyH8uFrEFdWbqVTHAe0G0pKly4NK1K30dKrSGYJw%3D%3D" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://c24cdn.co/restricted/sliced-media/59b2c60d2e764a25bd4a8e2d6f15cb31.webm?Expires=1584401901&amp;GoogleAccessId=microservice-writer%40coresystem-171219.iam.gserviceaccount.com&amp;Signature=JGbxZYS0u2rI2gY%2BjXThKj9KkIMBDfLvW9XEImWdtfzMFNpUBBm33B7wM3XYD01JLKcMD%2BlqfWf%2FqzMFAgW2zQH07NvGKzdkYFIgwxgCUQha8ws%2FLqoJyLMiz8UeXr5Smqqjr%2FiFrLLc6HmCnYfP8g7Y%2BJ%2FJoQuHmVeZjJIKxz957SZEOQ8QIQqtbIusK%2B0uqQzvyyW4vStDF7RvjZwp44b1H0pqzsby2bjCYspacgv9JM712Z72sZdercFFczC5BR%2FxT0jXFxYn6XiRhfE0HO1e24qFiR1A%2B78Ems3A3ZdQylaVDZ4UfVX13iofy2l0LWdXMjEynLxSz7cNPGtDpg%3D%3D" type="video/webm"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: The [HTML](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AEIkEc4VZmNTtKU&cid=7D4697A73BE7814D&id=7D4697A73BE7814D%21106&parId=root&o=OneUp) you have shared, does not contain the `video` tag element which you are looking for.

Comment: What error are you getting? Try this, `WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@id = 'innerframe']/iframe")));

element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//video[@id='mediaplayer']/soucre"); print(element.text);`

Comment: @Kamal the video html contains the video tag i want

Comment: @AliCSE element after writing the switch line and trying to get a text inside the frame element not found

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you are using is incorrect as there is a typing error in it, you have used `soucre` instead of `source` and the structure you have used to get it is also incorrect.
So, try to use the below code, it should work fine.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='innerframe']/iframe"))

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='mediacontent']//video").text
```

Comment: There is not content is the iframe as per the html shared.

Comment: @supputuri Yes you are correct, however i could see that the OP has edited the question and in the updated question he has put in the html structure of the elements he is operating on, so i have answered according to it.

Comment: I am forced to downvote this answer. `ID, "innerframe"` belongs to `<div>` but not to `<iframe>` tag, how can you **switch_to_it**?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes my bad, didn’t read the HTML properly. Have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out !!

Comment: @SameerArora Reverted back my downvote. However being a regular contributor you should encourage the _new contributors_ to add text based HTML instead of a link/picture.

Comment: @DebanjanB yes going forward i would :)

Comment: @SameerArora thanks for reply but i tried your code not working also at first i copied your code gave me type error __init__ takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given i think it’s missing parentheses and added them give error on the next line this time element not found